# Does Rylai's and Spellvamp apply on Continuous Magic Damage effects?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Rylai's and Spellvamp apply on Continuous Magic Damage effects, such as Teemo's Toxic Shot(`E`) and Malzahar's Malefic Visions(`E`)?

Answer (score 1):

Rylai's Crystal Scepter works with Damage over Time effects(DoT), it is reapplied for each tick but it only slows 15%. [source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1892067)

DoTs also tricker spell vamp. [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp)